# Exponentiated Operators? ($e^{\hat{A}+\hat{B}} \ne e^{\hat{B}+\hat{A}}$)

Tags: operator-theory, power-series, exponential-function

Given,

$$
e^{\hat{A}+\hat{B}} = e^{\hat{B}}e^{\hat{A}}
$$

I then consider the series expansion of both exponentials. This then leads to a particular order of operation derived from the order of addition in the exponential.

Am I correct in deducing that operators when inside the exponential function can no longer be moved in sequence of addition i.e.

$$
\hat{A}+\hat{B} \ne \hat{B}+\hat{A}
$$

(this would then apply by extrapolation to all operators inside functions since all functions can be expanded in series form)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "no longer associative" here. Can you write out an equation?

Comment: I forgot to reverse them. See edit

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "no longer associative."

Comment: Do I have the wrong word? By associative I mean $A+B = B+A$

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane That's "commutative". Associative is $(A+B)+C=A+(B+C)$.

Comment: I initially thought that too but most operators don't commute in the sense of $[A,B] \ne 0$ and I didn't mean the multiplicative commutation relation (ie. $AB - BA$). Is this still the correct word to use? If so I'll edit :)

Comment: a+b = b+a is called commutative, Associativity is  a + (b+c) = (a+b)+c

Comment: I believe $e^Ae^B\ne e^{A+B}$ unless $[A,B]=0$, that is, $AB=BA$.

Comment: Edited to totally avoid the words "commutative" or "associative" as I don't want to confuse the question! :)

Comment: If you define an operation $+$ by $e^{A+B} = e^B e^A$, then this operation "+" is not the ordinary addition defined between operators. You are just using a single symbol to refer to two completely different things.